# telling runit to pick up a new service immediately

Tags: linux, daemon, daemontools, runit

As a happy user of runit - I am curious if it is possible to send a signal to the main process (or similar) telling it to look *now* at the service directory? the current behaviour is < 5 seconds (seems much faster most of the time) between scans for new services - but I thought it would be nice if I could also tell it (in cases where the 5 second worst case is annoying - rare - but annoying).

Comment: I'd also like to know how to do this! It looks like the very similar s6 has a way to do it (with `s6scanclt -a`) but runit looks to be missing it.

Comment: I never found a solution - but it turned out not to matter for me - for some reason it is always faster than 5 seconds, or at least seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

`runsvdir` continuously monitors its service directory.  The delay is unfortunately arbitrary.  From the man page:

> At least every five seconds `runsvdir` checks whether the time of the
>   last modification, the inode, or the device, of the services directory
>   *dir* has changed.  If so, it re-scans the service directory, and if it
>   sees a new subdirectory, or new symlink to a directory, in *dir*, it
>   starts a new `runsv(8)` process...

The man page goes on to describe the TERM and HUP signals, both of which shut down the service.  There is no mention of a refresh.